# How to lateral join a function

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10, lateral-join

I'm not sure if my question is correct but this is what I'm trying to do.

I have a table `errorlog` with field `link` and I have a function `http_get` (based on `pgsql-http` that gives me the `status` of the `link`)

I believe I need to do a lateral join like so:

```
SELECT
    el.link,
    hg.status
FROM
    errorlog AS el
    LEFT OUTER JOIN LATERAL http_get(el.link) AS hg ON true
WHERE el.link IS NOT NULL ;
```

But it's not giving me any results. How does one apply a function like this to a table?

`errorlog` table:

```
+----+---------------------+
| id | link                |
+----+---------------------+
| 1  | http://www.test.com |
+----+---------------------+
| 2  | http://www.link.com |
+----+---------------------+
```

`pgsql-http:` https://github.com/pramsey/pgsql-http

**Update:** 
I've tried these queries:

```
SELECT
    el.link,
    (http_get(el.link)).status
FROM
    errorlog AS el
WHERE el.link IS NOT NULL ;
```

Result: `No records found.`

```
SELECT
    el.link,
    hg.status
FROM
    errorlog AS el, http_get(el.link) AS hg
WHERE el.link IS NOT NULL ;
```

Result: `No records found.`

However, this works:

`select * from http_get('http://test.com')`

Comment: Are you sure `http_get()` returns anything? Did you call that on its own with a hardcoded URL?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes this works `select * from http_get('http://test.com')`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I found the issue, my `link` field was deleted for some reason, it may be a dbeaver issue where I was deleting a few records but somehow deleted all (or perhaps user error).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query has to give you at least as many result rows as `errorlog` has. If it doesn't, there must have been an error.

Comment: I've updated the original post at the bottom with what I've tried and what works and doesn't. It's strange that the examples they provide works but when I join it with another table, it fails.

Comment: Your first query is missing parentheses: `(http_get(el.link)).status`. Your second query is no outer join. I don't see the connection to the original question.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply invoke the function in the `SELECT` clause?

```sql
SELECT
    el.link,
    (http_get(el.link)).status
FROM
    errorlog AS el
WHERE el.link IS NOT NULL ;
```

In addition, function calls are always executed implicitly as `LATERAL` and a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` is basically useless here, so if you insist on executing the function lateral, then do this:

```sql
SELECT
    el.link,
    hg.status
FROM
    errorlog AS el, http_get(el.link) AS hg
WHERE el.link IS NOT NULL ;
```

Comment: I tried the first query already but it's giving me a `tax error at or near "."` error, there are no example in the `pgsql-http` github that shows you can use the function in the select statement.  I've also tried the second query you've provided and it didn't work, I should state this.

Comment: OK, I think you sorted out the original issue (apparently no data in table), right? So my answer is just showing some other syntactical variants to achieve the same with varying flexibility.